# Qual é a melhor opção a ser usada em relação ao desempenho

Tags: javascript, desempenho

Preciso fazer com que todos produtos sumam da tela, mas tenho produtos que já não estão na tela. Então minha pergunta é: 
Será que se eu esconder somente os produtos que estão visíveis terá um melhor desempenho? ao invés de dar um `.hide()` em todos os produtos, mesmo nos que já estão invisíveis

Por exemplo, qual seria o melhor desempenho desses dois trechos de código abaixo

```
$(".produto").hide().attr('invisible',true);
```

OU

```
$(".produto[invisible=false]").hide().attr('invisible',true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seletores simples como `.produto` sempre vai ser mais rápidos que seletores complexos para buscar

Porém para mudar propriedades é provável que `[invisible=false]` seja mais rápido, já que alterar elementos DOM que já estão no corpo da página é mais custoso, então neste caso a consulta irá trazer menos elementos e isto tornará o processo com `.hide` mais rápido, pois teremos menos elementos.

### Classes e perfomance

No entanto que a consulta de classes geralmente é mais rápida que a consulta de atributos, então ao invés de usar `.attr('invisible',true);` utilize uma classe, como:

Ocultar:

```
$(".produto:not(.hide)").addClass("hide");
```

Exibe:

```
$(".produto.visible").removeClass("hide");
```

Se quiser usar o efeito animado:

```
$(".produto:not(.hide)").hide(400, function() {
    $(this).addClass("hide");
});

$(".produto.hide").removeClass("hide").show();
```

Porém note que este tipo de optimização é minima.

### Seletor `:hide` e `:visibile`

Também pode-se usar os seletores `:hide` e `:visibile` pode ser útil, por exemplo:

```
$(".produto:visible").hide();
```

e

```
$(".produto:hide").show();
```

Comment: Seguindo essa ideia de usar uma classe para `visible` e outra para `invisible` ganhei 2 segundos de performance na hora de executar o código :D

Answer (score 2):

> Aviso: infelizmente o [jsperf](http://jsperf.com), que seria a ferramenta mais prática para testar o que digo na minha resposta, [tem tido problemas de estabilidade](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/18#issuecomment-113569132), e não estou conseguindo usá-lo no momento. Portanto considere que alguns dos meus argumentos podem ser tanto confirmados quanto desmentidos por um teste real de performance. E não se esqueça que a melhor opção pode variar de acordo com o browser.

Para entender os possíveis gargalos de performance nesses trechos de código, vamos ver quais operações eles realizam:

1. `$(...)`– Cria uma array de objetos jQuery contendo todos os elementos que atendem ao seletor passado. Sempre que possível o jQuery usa a função nativa `document.querySelectorAll` para isso.
2. `.hide()` – Executa um loop sobre a nossa array de elementos, escondendo todos eles, um a um.
3. `.attr('nome', valor)` – Executa outro loop sobre a array, definindo o valor do atributo para todos eles, um a um.

A diferença entre os seus dois trechos de código está na operação **1**, mas pode impactar nas outras duas.

Em teoria, selecionar apenas os elementos de um classe (como `".produto"`) é mais rápido que selecionar os elementos dessa classe que atendam a algum critério adicional (como `".produto[invisible=false]"`). Porém isso pode depender de como o algoritmo de seleção é implementado em cada browser. E, também em teoria, selecionar atributos é mais lento – o que também depende da implementação.

Mas, supondo que o primeiro seletor é mesmo mais rápido, e as demais operações (os loops) são iguais nos dois trechos de código que você postou, então a primeira versão é mais rápida que a segunda, certo? Não necessariamente! A primeira versão tem potencial para selecionar mais elementos da página, já que é menos restritiva que a segunda, e isso pode influenciar no tempo de execução dos loops.

Imagine uma página com muitos produtos (sei lá, 5.000), mas apenas 10 visíveis. A primeira versão pode até selecionar mais rápido, mas vai selecionar 5.000 elementos, e depois iterar sobre esses 5.000 elementos duas vezes. Já a segunda iria selecionar só 10 elementos, e fazer 2 loops sobre esses 10, o que teoricamente é bem mais rápido e pode compensar a lentidão maior da seleção.

#### Conclusão

Em questões de desempenho como esta, a única maneira de se fazer um teste realista é reproduzir todas as condições da sua aplicação, e ver como cada variação se comporta. O que importa é como elas se comportam nessas situações, e não em qualquer situação possível. E se você testar as duas variações na sua aplicação, com usuários reais, nos diversos browsers que você pretende suportar, e ambas se saírem aparentemente bem, esqueça a questão do desempenho. O custo (em tempo, esforço) de micro-otimizações desse tipo é muito maior do que a melhora de desempenho que elas possam vir a proporcionar, e que geralmente é desprezível.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro será executado mais rápido, já que será necessário apenas encontrar todos os elementos com classe produto, enquanto o segundo código terá que encontrar esse mesmos elementos e, depois, verificar seu atributo *invisible*.